# Accessing a for loop variable inside and if statement

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following code but it gives me an error. Can anyone help?

```
<span th:each="p,iter : ${pp}">
    <span th:text="${p.title}">[default]</span>
    <span
                  th:if="${#lists.size(hh) >= iter.index
                  th:text="${hh[iter.index].name}">
    </span>
  ...
```

I get this error message:

> Error during execution of processor org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardIfAttrProcessor'

It is because of the `list.size(hh) >= iterStat.index`. If I don't have the `iterStat.index` then it is ok. But as this is dynamic I want to use the index of the iteration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing } in `th:if="${#lists.size(hh) >= iter.index`